# Why the reduxform submit handle does not receive any data?

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux-form

I am working on constructing an example to replicate the problem, but the code is by far very complex and it will take me a while to complete. Therefore I will lay out some minimum information. Hopefully the root cause of the problem is very obvious and someone can identify the issue before I finish my example.

I passed the following handler to the form's `onSubmit` property:

```
  handleReduxForm(reactthing, values, more) {
    console.log(reactthing);
    console.log(values);
    console.log(more);
}
```

It prints out the following

[image]

So no doubt the handler has been called.

However, instead of receiving any data captured on the form as the first parameter to the function, I got

**First parameter:** seems to be proxy of a react dom object

**Second parameter:** an event object

**Third parameter:** Just to ensure I did not miss the form data. It is `undefined` at the moment.

The form is rather simple:

```
const checkoutForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, submitting, pristine } = props;


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


          <div className={styles.buttons}>
            <button
              className={`btn btn-primary ${styles['btn-submit']}`}
              type="submit"
              disabled={submitting || pristine}
            >
              Buy
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const CheckoutForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'checkout',
  asyncValidate,
})(checkoutForm);

CheckoutForm.propTypes = {
  submitting: PropTypes.bool,
  pristine: PropTypes.bool,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

So what's wrong with my submit handler? Why it is not getting any form data?

**EDIT**

Here is an example: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh0qVhrYYi7iBqFXjSY

Following are the listing of the main files:

**Container.js**

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import CheckoutForm from './Form';

const testHandler = (a, b, c) => {
  console.log(` testHandler ${a}, ${b}, ${c}`); 
  console.log(` testHandler ${Object.keys(a)}, ${Object.values(a)}`);
  console.log(` testHandler ${Object.keys(b)}, ${Object.values(b)}`);  
}

class Container extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
        Smart component
        </h1>
        <CheckoutForm 
          handleSubmit={testHandler}
         />
      </div>
      )
  }
}


export default  Container ;
```

**Form.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';

import Immutable from 'immutable';


const  { DOM: { input, select, textarea } } = React;


// <Field name="data" component={input}/>
// Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` 
// nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of bound createElement.
const checkoutForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, submitting, pristine } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h3>
            Checkout
          </h3>
          <div>
            <label>Data</label>
            <Field name="name" component="input" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div className='buttons'>
            <button
              className='btn btn-primary btn-submit'
              type="submit"
              disabled={submitting || pristine}
            >
              Buy
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const CheckoutForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'checkout'
})(checkoutForm);

export default CheckoutForm;
```

Output from my example:

[image]

**The dependencies**

Using `immutable` 3.8.1 and `redux-form` 6.6.1

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's enough code in the example to see what's really going wrong, at least I can't really detect anything wrong with it. Could you post more?

Comment: I think I can reproduce the problem here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh0qVhrYYi7iBqFXjSY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is change the bit in `Container.js` from

```
<CheckoutForm 
  handleSubmit={testHandler}
/>
```

to:

```
<CheckoutForm 
  onSubmit={testHandler}
/>
```

I got a map with values when I tried that change.

Comment: This is very strange. You can see this line '<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>'. This supposes to pass the function to onsubmit property, right? But thanks for finding a solution!

Comment: With `onSubmit` you're registering on the event that redux-form fires when your form submits, so that allows you to get the values. In your case you were passing your own version of redux-form's `handleSubmit`, which obviously doesn't work :)